# c:redirect is not working in weblogic server

Tags: spring, jsp, weblogic-10.x

i have a spring application and  while i am deploying it in weblogic server it is giving 404 Error.

in web.xml i given index.jsp as welcome file and from that i am redirecting to controller class but it is not working

here is my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

here is my index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/result"/>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller class method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getResults(ModelMap map){

        map.put("userList","null");
        System.out.println("result page ...");
        return "result";

    }
```

the above logic is woking in tomcat but it is not working in weblogic server
please any body help me.
here i created as a war and i am deploying in weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

```
<url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

**Edit**

Try doing the following

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getResults(ModelMap map){

    map.put("userList","null");
    System.out.println("result page ...");
    return "redirect:"+ Your_Url;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i followed your approach it is not woking

Comment: first of all it is not coming into this method